# how can I avoid to many OR statements in a mysql query?

Tags: php, mysql

I am writing a code, where I have to produce a query with many OR statements, and I think there is a more comfortable way to this than:

```
foreach ($plz as &$value) {
    if (empty($i)) {
        $query = "WHERE plz='$value'";
    } else {
        $query = "$query OR plz='$value'";
    }
    $i++;
}
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table $query");
while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    //do something
}
```

Comment: Have you tried the IN statement?

Comment: instead of writting `$query = "$query OR plz='$value'";` you could use `$query .= " OR plz = '$value'";` ([.= operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) to cocatenate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have multiple values a column may take, just connect them using the [`IN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in) operator:

Instead of writing

```
... WHERE col=1 OR col=2 OR col=3
```

just write

```
... WHERE col IN (1,2,3)
```

To collect all entries in PHP, use an array and [`implode()`](http://php.net/implode) later on:

```
// collecting values
$vals = array();
$vals[] = 1;
$vals[] = 2;
// ...

// add them to your query
$query .= ' WHERE col IN ( ' . implode( ',', $vals ) . ')';

// execute the query ...
```

In case your values are not integer, but need to be enclosed in apostrophes within the query, insert them that way into the array in the first place:

```
$vals[] = "'my string value'";
```

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for ;

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE plz in ('value1', 'value2', 'value3')
```

Be aware of [SQL injections](http://bobby-tables.com/)...

Comment: sql injections are not possible, because the array $plz is generated.

Answer (score 1):

If the column `plz` is INT type, and all `$plz` are also integers, then:

```
$query = 'WHERE plz IN( ' . implode(',', $plz) . ')';
```

would work. Otherwise, trying this might work(not tested):

```
$query = 'WHERE plz IN( \'' . implode("','", $plz) . '\')';
```

Comment: okey it is `"'" . implode("', '", $plz) . "'"` but 1) it does not work if $plz has no value and 2) that's dangerous.

Comment: A. If $plz is empty, OP can use an `IF` statement. That was obvious.

B. It's dangerous if `$plz` is string. But again, OP didn't mention anything yet.